# Prevent Flash Updates - Win 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, uac

I wish to prevent the Adobe Flash player from checking for updates on all domain computers. In principle it's as simple as creating a UTF-8 format file name mms.cfg in the `%windir%\system32\macromed\flash` folder. (The file only needs the line `AutoUpdateDisable=1`.) While this works fine via a logon script on XP and Server 2003 machines it's not working on Win 7 because of the UAC, which I'd rather not disable if practical.

I'm after a way to create/copy the file without user intervention, preferably at logon. Can this be done with a script, bearing in mind the target location, or do I need to create an MSI package and use GPO to install it, which seems like an awful lot of trouble to go through for such a simple thing?

Comment: Why does it have to be a logon, and not startup?  Are you really using a login script and not a startup script?  A login script shouldn't be able to write there even on XP unless the users have administrator access.  Startup scripts should be able to write there on Win7 even with the UAC on.

Comment: @Zoredache - My only excuse is brain fade caused by just having gone through a company name change and all that entails. Everyone did indeed have full admin rights on their XP machines (not my idea) but I'm not replicating that onto Win 7. If you care to post this as an answer I can accept it and get on with other things. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to write to `%windir%\system32\macromed\flash` from a script, it would be much better to use a [computer startup script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779329(WS.10).aspx).

A normal user will typically not have write access to that folder.

You can also [Group Policy preferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy#Group_Policy_Preferences) to copy files onto the machines if you only care about Windows 7?